# ListView does not display data from HashMap

Tags: android, listview, dictionary, hash

I'm currently new to Android and I am trying to solve a problem.
I did a Quizz App (using OpenClassRoom MOOC - French website) and I need to create a Rank Score.
To do so, I have two (three actually but I only need to use two of them here) activities: MainActivity and HistoricActivity.

I am sending from MainActivity to HistoricActivity a HashMap, storing both player's name and its score.

In order to display my data in a listView, I need an adapter, which I created.

So in my HistoricAdapter, I extended from BaseAdapter and overrided getView method.
In this method, I am trying to loop over my HashMap and for each game, to display both the name of the player and its score.

First game, it is working perfectly.
Second game, here comes the trouble... It displays the second name of the player and it's score but it also deleted the result of my first game. It goes so:

First game: Lena 3 (name and score)
Second game: Max 0, Max 0 (first line is replaced by Max 0)
Third game: Jack 1, Jack 1, Jack 1
(and so on)

The result expected should be: (For the second game) Lena 3, Max 0

Could aynone help please? I think that I am seriously missing a big step! 
Thank you :)

```java
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.example.topquiz.R;
import com.example.topquiz.adapter.HistoricTableAdapter;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class HistoricActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Button mBackButton;
    private ListView mListView;

    private HashMap<String, List<Integer>> tabScores;

    private String player;
    private int score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_historic);

        mBackButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.activity_historic_back_button);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.activity_historic_table_listview);

        tabScores = (HashMap<String, List<Integer>>) getIntent().getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.TREE_MAP_SAVED);

        HistoricTableAdapter adapter = new HistoricTableAdapter(this, tabScores);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        mBackButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                finish();
            }
        });
    }


}
```

```java
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.topquiz.R;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;


public class HistoricTableAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity context;
    HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map;

    private String key;
    private int singleValue;


    public HistoricTableAdapter(Activity context, HashMap<String, List<Integer>> map) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
        this.map = map;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (map.size() < 5) {
            return map.size();
        } else {
            return 5;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return map.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {

        final ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_historic_list_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.playerNameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_historic_list_view_name_player);
            holder.scorePlayerTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.activity_historic_list_view_score_player);

            view.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }


        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Integer>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
                key = entry.getKey();
                holder.playerNameTxt.setText(key);
                for (int singleValue : entry.getValue()) {
                    holder.scorePlayerTxt.setText(String.valueOf(singleValue));
                }

        }

        return view;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        private TextView playerNameTxt;
        private TextView scorePlayerTxt;
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, you are fetching **every value** on the hashmap **for every view**. You need to get the value at position and display it there. `int position` inside `getView()` is there for a reason, it literally points out the position (index) in a list. `getView()` is called multiple times, it's called once for each textview you see.

Comment: why are you using a hashmap for list

Comment: Also you should use a list, it should be way easier to manage that way.

Comment: Remove the for loop from `getview` and move it to `constructor` of HistoricTableAdapter and store the names and corresponding scores in separate lists in  the constructor and use those lists in your get view to display data by position

Comment: @FurkanYurdakul It explains why as I was debugging, I noticed the cursor was going into getView() multiple times.

ManojPerumarath It's because I wanted to get a key/value system. I am sending a HashMap from MainActivity. But reading your comment, it is pretty clear that I should send a List and not a HashMap.
I'm gonna give it a go with a List.

If it's not working, I'll use Ravi 's help!